# Error attempting to send an e-mail

Tags: .net, asp.net

I am trying to send the user an email and I used this code:

```
MailMessage pMail = new MailMessage();

pMail.From = new MailAddress("email@website.com");

pMail.To.Add(new MailAddress(eBox.Text));

pMail.Subject = "Elwazefa Password Reset";
pMail.Body = "Content";

SmtpClient sClient = new SmtpClient();
sClient.Send(pMail);

prError.Text = "An Email with further instructions has been sent to you";
```

and I am getting this error:

> The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address.

I also configured the smtp setting in the web.config file and tested it and it's working fine

thanks

Comment: What is the value in `eBox.Text` ?? That most likely causes the issue....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like `ebox.Text` doesn't contain a valid email address.  Check the value you are entering in this textbox is a well formed email address.

Comment: the email i entered is like this name@domain.com